Keyboard covering TextEditor in SwiftUI
im facing an issue where my keyboard will not move down with my texteditor thus covering the text.
my customized text editor so i can use a placeholder
    struct TextEditorWithPlaceholder: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if text.isEmpty {
                VStack {
                    Text(placeholder)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .padding(.leading, 6)
                        .opacity(0.6)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }

            VStack {
                TextEditor(text: $text)
                    .frame(minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 200)
                    .opacity(text.isEmpty ? 0.85 : 1)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

an example of how im placing the editor in a view
Section(header: Text("Additional info")) {
TextEditorWithPlaceholder(text: $callDetails, placeholder: "placerholder text")
.focused($infoField)
}



Assuming the text editor is in a Form/List, you can wrap with a ScrollViewReader and scroll to the bottom of the text editor whenever the text changes.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            Form {
                Section("Foo") {
                    ForEach(0..<10) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Additional info")) {
                    TextEditorWithPlaceholder(text: $text, placeholder: "placerholder text")
                        .id("Text Editor")
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: text) {
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo("Text Editor", anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

// I have also simplified the structure of TextEditorWithPlaceholder
struct TextEditorWithPlaceholder: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            if text.isEmpty {
                Text(placeholder)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.leading, 6)
                    .opacity(0.6)
            }
            
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .opacity(text.isEmpty ? 0.85 : 1)
        }
        .frame(minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 200)
    }
}

